# TeamCity hanged afer test is passed

Tags: teamcity, functional-testing, nunit-2.5.9

We run the functional test on TeamCity.

The test is passed but hanged and fails after a time out of 1 hour.

And TeamCity throws the following error

WARN  JetBrains.Container.Log4netDefaultLoggerInitializer - Unhandled exception in current domain: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain.,

when running our test directly with NUnit GUI within Visual studio 2015 we have no issues and the test is passing.

can someone please let me know what is this issue related to?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the NUnit runner? What version of TeamCity do you use?
The most simplest solution is to use NUnit 3 with the NUni runner. It will definitely help.
PS The latest versions of TeamCity supports NUnit 3.

Comment: Hi Nokolay, thanks for your prompt reply.  I am using TeamCity Version 9.1.1 and nUnit version 2.6.4.